# Django REST Framework Batch PUT (Update)

Tags: json, django, django-rest-framework

I have implemented viewsets and routers, making an API that returns me some specific fields, I get the info correctly, and I can update (PUT) **JUST ONE** of the details in the JSON, one by one, and I need to update all of them at the same time.

I have this in my **serializers.py**

```
class OCompraDetalleSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
#   producto = ProductoSerializer(many=False)
    item = serializers.RelatedField(source='producto.modelo')
    descripcion = serializers.RelatedField(source='producto.descripcion')
    unidad = serializers.RelatedField(source='producto.unidad')
#   ocompra = OCompraSerializer(many = False)
    class Meta:
        model = OCompraDetalle
        fields = ('url','item','descripcion','unidad','cantidad_ordenada','cantidad_recibida','fecha_entrega','precio','epc')
```

The API returns me this

```
HTTP 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept
Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS

[
    {
        "url": "http://localhost:8000/api/ocompradetalle/1/", 
        "item": "AANS/428375", 
        "descripcion": "SPLICING KIT SHIPPING ASSEMBLY", 
        "unidad": "PZA", 
        "cantidad_ordenada": "1", 
        "cantidad_recibida": "1", 
        "fecha_entrega": "2015-07-14", 
        "precio": "500", 
        "epc": "0320CAF425"
    }, 
    {
        "url": "http://localhost:8000/api/ocompradetalle/5/", 
        "item": "AANS/53042", 
        "descripcion": "NOZZLE F-1/2 W/BLOW OFF CAP,LOCKWASHERS", 
        "unidad": "PZA", 
        "cantidad_ordenada": "5", 
        "cantidad_recibida": "0", 
        "fecha_entrega": "2015-07-14", 
        "precio": "300", 
        "epc": "0436F0BECD"
    },  
...
```

So the ALLOW section indicates that I CANT put, but if I open a single one detail, I get this:

```
HTTP 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept
Allow: GET, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS

{
    "url": "http://localhost:8000/api/ocompradetalle/1/", 
    "item": "AANS/428375", 
    "descripcion": "SPLICING KIT SHIPPING ASSEMBLY", 
    "unidad": "PZA", 
    "cantidad_ordenada": "1", 
    "cantidad_recibida": "1", 
    "fecha_entrega": "2015-07-14", 
    "precio": "500", 
    "epc": "0320CAF425"
}
```

Making it possible to UPDATE, my question is:
How can I PUT (Update) the whole JSON at the same time instead of making an Update for every single entry?

**NOTE:** the`'item','descripcion','unidad'` fields comes from another Model, thats why I have the `ProductoSerializer` commented, so I decided to include the specific values in the json.

**NOTE 2:** I only need to PUT or Update the `cantidad_recibida` value for every entry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django REST Framework does not allow for batch modifications to objects, but a package has been created that brings batch updating. [Django REST Framework Bulk](https://github.com/miki725/django-rest-framework-bulk) is a package that allows you to add a mixin to any generic view (including ViewSets) that can give it the ability to bulk create, update, or delete objects.

It can be made to [work with routers](https://github.com/miki725/django-rest-framework-bulk/issues/11) with slight modifications. This should allow you to do what you are looking for.

> **NOTE 2:** I only need to PUT or Update the cantidad_recibida value for every entry.

This sounds like you are looking for `PATCH`, though that doesn't allow for object creation in the same way that `PUT` allows.

Comment: Excelent!! the `work with routers` link worked for me ;)
Thank you!!